# Detect user inactivity in DialogFragment and logout after some time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

There are many activities and dialog fragments in my app. I searched about detecting activity and came to know about `onUserInterAction` function but it detects in activity for activities only but not while a dialog fragment is open.

Comment: A Fragment is always attached to an Activity, thus you can use it.

Comment: `Fragment` and `Activity` are both closely coupled so you can use `onUserInteraction` method even in `Fragment` or you can even use callback concept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by creating a wrapper on the dialog's Window  callback.

YourDialogFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    UserInteractionInterceptor.wrapWindowCallback(getDialog().getWindow(), getActivity());
}
```

UserInteractionInterceptor.java

```
public class UserInteractionInterceptor {

public static void wrapWindowCallback(Window window, FragmentActivity activity) {
    Window.Callback originalCallback = window.getCallback();

    window.setCallback(new Window.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            return originalCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            return originalCallback.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event);
        }
        //This is the important override
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(activity != null)
                    activity.onUserInteraction();
            }
            return originalCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return originalCallback.dispatchTrackballEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return originalCallback.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
            return originalCallback.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreatePanelView(int featureId) {
            return originalCallback.onCreatePanelView(featureId);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
            return originalCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
            return originalCallback.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
            return originalCallback.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
            return originalCallback.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onWindowAttributesChanged(WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs) {
            originalCallback.onWindowAttributesChanged(attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onContentChanged() {
            originalCallback.onContentChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            originalCallback.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToWindow() {
            originalCallback.onAttachedToWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
            originalCallback.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
            originalCallback.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSearchRequested() {
            return originalCallback.onSearchRequested();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public boolean onSearchRequested(SearchEvent searchEvent) {
            return originalCallback.onSearchRequested(searchEvent);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
            return originalCallback.onWindowStartingActionMode(callback);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback, int type) {
            return originalCallback.onWindowStartingActionMode(callback, type);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
            originalCallback.onActionModeStarted(mode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
            originalCallback.onActionModeFinished(mode);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Kotlin version:

In your Dialog:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    UserInteractionInterceptor.wrapWindowCallback(dialog.window, activity)
}
```

and the UserInteractionInterceptor Class:

```
object UserInteractionInterceptor {
fun wrapWindowCallback(window: Window, activity: FragmentActivity?) {
    val originalCallback: Window.Callback = window.callback

    window.callback = object : Window.Callback {
        override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
        }

        override fun dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event)
        }

        //This is the important override
        override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                activity?.onUserInteraction()
            }
            return originalCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
        }

        override fun dispatchTrackballEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.dispatchTrackballEvent(event)
        }

        override fun dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event)
        }

        override fun dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event)
        }

        @Nullable
        override fun onCreatePanelView(featureId: Int): View? {
            return originalCallback.onCreatePanelView(featureId)
        }

        override fun onCreatePanelMenu(featureId: Int, p1: Menu): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, p1)
        }

        override fun onPreparePanel(featureId: Int, view: View?, p2: Menu): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, p2)
        }

        override fun onMenuOpened(featureId: Int, p1: Menu): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.onMenuOpened(featureId, p1)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(featureId: Int, p1: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, p1)
        }

        override fun onWindowAttributesChanged(attrs: WindowManager.LayoutParams?) {
            originalCallback.onWindowAttributesChanged(attrs)
        }

        override fun onContentChanged() {
            originalCallback.onContentChanged()
        }

        override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
            originalCallback.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        }

        override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
            originalCallback.onAttachedToWindow()
        }

        override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
            originalCallback.onDetachedFromWindow()
        }

        override fun onPanelClosed(featureId: Int, p1: Menu) {
            originalCallback.onPanelClosed(featureId, p1)
        }

        override fun onSearchRequested(): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.onSearchRequested()
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        override fun onSearchRequested(searchEvent: SearchEvent?): Boolean {
            return originalCallback.onSearchRequested(searchEvent)
        }

        @Nullable
        override fun onWindowStartingActionMode(callback: ActionMode.Callback?): ActionMode? {
            return originalCallback.onWindowStartingActionMode(callback)
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Nullable
        override fun onWindowStartingActionMode(callback: ActionMode.Callback?, type: Int): ActionMode? {
            return originalCallback.onWindowStartingActionMode(callback, type)
        }

        override fun onActionModeStarted(mode: ActionMode?) {
            originalCallback.onActionModeStarted(mode)
        }

        override fun onActionModeFinished(mode: ActionMode?) {
            originalCallback.onActionModeFinished(mode)
        }
    }
}
```

}